# How to find a valume of a prism when when we are not given the height?

Tags: triangles

So I was learning how to find the surface area and volume. I came across few youtube tutorials which were simple. And in my book I found much harder problem. It asks me to find the volume of the prism when I'm given all sides of base instead of having only two (triangle width and height) and having height. I know that for finding the volume I need the base area multiply with height (A=Bh) but in this case my base area is already given AB=25CM BC=29CM AC=36CM and so is surface area (1620cm sqr) So I'm asked to find the volume given these things. I don't where do I start. This tutorial shows how to solve simpler problem than my. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZHXzB28Kxc  he has base's width and height together with prism's height. I I have everything but height. What do I do? How do I find height? Do I still use that formule to find base area? In my case 1/2*25*29*36 or what? I have no idea. Here I attach a pic of prism. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgyuK.jpg)

Comment: Can you define the "value" of a prism?

Comment: @Aniket Probably means “volume.”

Comment: Do you know how to find the surface area of a prism given its edge lengths?

Comment: @amd Yes, sorry, I meant Volume not value. I know how to find surface area of the prism given its edge lengths. I need to find lateral area first then add up with 2xbase area. I know that I have to use this formula to find out base area given its edge length 1/2 bh but in this case I'm given base area's length, width and length (25cm 26cm 36cm) What formula to use to find out base area?

Comment: @amd Okey, I know that first thing that I need to do is to find base area. Do I need to use formule for that like is showed in this video at 2:40 ? youtube.com/watch?v=sxt4OPZ7Urs if yes, how do I apply all 3 edges (25cm 29cm 36cm) to this formula?

Comment: @amd I already know how to calculate base area given all 3 edges. I need to use **Herom** Formula. Now I'm left with finding the height of the prism. What formula should I apply here to find the height of the prism given that I already have surface area of 1620cm (Sqr) and base area of 360cm(sqr) ?